# when I debugging code I found "Exception has occurred." in object_patch.dart file

Tags: flutter, api, dart, dart-async

NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: )

I cant solve this , because I can't understand this mean
but its can't received null

Comment: please share error log

Comment: debug your code. some where some var is null.